# How to test functions that interacts with database

Tags: python, database, unit-testing, pytest

I have the functions that performs some CRUD operations with database like this:

```py
def get_user_by_id(user_id):
    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.cursor(cursor_factory=extras.DictCursor)

    cursor.execute(
        'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = %s',
        (user_id, )
    )
    user = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()

    return user
```

I want to test it with pytest, but don't know the right way to do it.

For example to get user data from database I should first create it and then call tested function. But should I call my `create_user()` function at setup and then call tested `get_user_by_id()`? Or it would be better to populate database with some test data and then use it? Should I test this kind of functions at all?

Comment: It depends on your intention. if you want to test your function, you can insert date before hand using setup [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html) and then validate it.

Comment: are you trying to write a unit test or an integration test